# Voltage to keep my board safe

Tags: nodemcu, voltage-level, relay

I have recently made a home automation system using node mcu and relay module and i am powering both together using my 5V ,2A dc adapter and i am scared that if I'll keep using it for very long hours and that too daily my node mcu board would disrupt soon. So i wanted to ask that what to keep the minimum voltage. So to keep the board safe

Comment: to which pin on the NodeMcu is the 5 V input wired?

Comment: @Juraj it is the 3v3 pin

Comment: and it doesn't smoke?

Comment: @Juraj no it doesn't and i kept it running for 1 hr.

Comment: @Juraj i just wanna ask... should i lower the voltage or change the pin to keep my board safe...for longer hrs of running

Comment: @Juraj yes it has a vin pin..

Comment: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-devkit-v1.0/issues/15

Comment: @Juraj sir if i connect it to vin at 5v can keep it running daily for at least 11 to 10 hrs.?

Comment: it has a regulator on Vin. it can run 24/7 then

Comment: I'm not sure I'd trust it, after given it 5V instead of 3.3V for over an hour.

Comment: @Juraj how to check if it has a regulator

Comment: if it is a NodeMcu it has it